# How to create a jQuery function (a new jQuery method or plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I know that in JavaScript the syntax is as follows:

```
function myfunction(param){
  //some code
}
```

Is there a way to declare a function in jQuery that can be added to an element? For example:

```
$('#my_div').myfunction()
```

Comment: @RedEyedMonster - it makes *plenty* of sense. Ever used anything like jQuery datepicker? `$('#myDatePickerfield').datePicker();`

Comment: No I haven't but thanks for alerting me to it :)

Comment: @RedEyedMonster - You've probably used `$("#someElement").hide()` or `.addClass()`...

Comment: @RedEyedMonster: the OP is describing jQuery plugins, which are actually pretty common in JavaScript. See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 323, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.myfunction = function() {
      alert('hello world');
      return this;
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

Then you do

```
$('#my_div').myfunction();
```

Comment: Just to add something I thought important: please add - return this; after the alert. It will make the function chain-able.

Comment: Many right answers here. The jQuery-Docu shows the differences: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: @candide at which point `$('my_div').myfunction();`  will be call

Comment: @NikhilG $('my_div') refers to a tag `<my_div></my_div>`. You do need the hash sign there to refer to the id `my_div`.

Comment: This is a strange example because it doesn't really to anything to that element.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the doc.But from what I see in this doc, it should be:

`(function( $ ){ ... }( jQuery ));`

and not

`(function( $ ){ ... })( jQuery );`

Comment: That makes no difference @fpierrat

Answer (score 89):

In spite of all the answers you already received, it is worth noting that you do not need to write a plugin to use jQuery in a function. Certainly if it's a simple, one-time function, I believe writing a plugin is overkill. It could be done much more easily by just **passing the selector to the function as a parameter**. Your code would look something like this:

```
function myFunction($param) {
   $param.hide();  // or whatever you want to do
   ...
}

myFunction($('#my_div'));
```

*Note that the `$` in the variable name `$param` is not required. It is just a habit of mine to make it easy to remember that that variable contains a jQuery selector. You could just use `param` as well.*

Answer (score 44):

While there is a **plethora** of documentation / tutorials out there, the simple answer for your question is this:

```
// to create a jQuery function, you basically just extend the jQuery prototype
// (using the fn alias)

$.fn.myfunction = function () {
    // blah
};
```

Inside that function, the `this` variable corresponds to the jQuery wrapped set you called your function on. So something like:

```
$.fn.myfunction = function () {
    console.log(this.length);
};

$('.foo').myfunction();
```

... will flush to the console the number of elements with the class `foo`.

Of course, there is a bit more to semantics than that (as well as best practices, and all that jazz), so make sure you read up on it.

Answer (score 14):

To make a function available on jQuery objects you add it to the jQuery prototype (fn is a shortcut for prototype in jQuery) like this:

```
jQuery.fn.myFunction = function() {
    // Usually iterate over the items and return for chainability
    // 'this' is the elements returns by the selector
    return this.each(function() { 
         // do something to each item matching the selector
    }
}
```

This is usually called a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/VwPrm/

Answer (score 10):

Yup — what you’re describing is a jQuery plugin.

To write a jQuery plugin, you create a function in JavaScript, and assign it to a property on the object `jQuery.fn`.

E.g.

```
jQuery.fn.myfunction = function(param) {
    // Some code
}
```

Within your plugin function, the `this` keyword is set to the jQuery object on which your plugin was invoked. So, when you do:

```
$('#my_div').myfunction()
```

Then `this` inside `myfunction` will be set to the jQuery object returned by `$('#my_div')`.

See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring for the full story.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(function () {
    //declare function 
    $.fn.myfunction = function () {
        return true;
    };
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    //call function
    $("#my_div").myfunction();
});
```

Comment: I don't think that the mismatch in closing parens and braces are the only problems with this code. Please fix.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use **extend** (the way you create jQuery plugins):

```
$.fn.extend(
{
    myfunction: function () 
    {
    },

    myfunction2: function () 
    {
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
$('#my_div').myfunction();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own jQuery plugins(function which can be called on selected elements) like below:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myFunc = function(param1, param2){
        //this - jquery object holds your selected elements
    }
})( jQuery );
```

Call it later like:

```
$('div').myFunc(1, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, methods you apply to elements selected using jquery, are called jquery plugins and there is [a good amount of info on authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) within the jquery docs.

Its worth noting that jquery *is* just javascript, so there is nothing special about a "jquery method".

Comment: _'there is nothing special about a "jquery method"'_ - Yes there is: a "jQuery method" works on a jQuery object. (But yes, jQuery _is_ just JS...)

Answer (score 4):

Create a "colorize" method:

```
$.fn.colorize = function custom_colorize(some_color) {
    this.css('color', some_color);
    return this;
}
```

Use it:

```
$('#my_div').colorize('green');
```

This simple-ish example combines the best of [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) in the jQuery docs, and answers from [@Candide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093389/673991), [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093344/673991).

- A [named function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15336347/673991) may improve stack traces, etc.
- A custom method that returns `this` [may be chained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37992692/673991). (Thanks @Potheek.)

Answer (score 3):

You can always do this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
   myfunction: function(param){
       // code here
   },
});
OR
jQuery.extend({
   myfunction: function(param){
       // code here
   },
});
$(element).myfunction(param);
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to extend the jQuery object via it's prototype (aka [write a jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)). This would mean that every new object created through calling the jQuery function (`$(selector/DOM element)`) would have this method.

Here is a very simple example:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function () {
    alert('it works');
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hmJNa/)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest example to making any function in jQuery is

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    exists: function() { return this.length }
});

if($(selector).exists()){/*do something here*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Define a function in jQuery</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.myFunction = function() { 
        alert('You have successfully defined your function!'); 
    }
    $(".call-btn").click(function(){
        $.fn.myFunction();
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="call-btn">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```