# Need explanation for this usage of block as method parameter

Tags: objective-c

This is a snippet from AFNetworking's sample code:

```
+ (void)globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block {
    [[AFAppDotNetAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"stream/0/posts/stream/global" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
        NSArray *postsFromResponse = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
        NSMutableArray *mutablePosts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[postsFromResponse count]];
        for (NSDictionary *attributes in postsFromResponse) {
            Post *post = [[Post alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
            [mutablePosts addObject:post];
        }

        if (block) {
            block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutablePosts], nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (block) {
            block([NSArray array], error);
        }
    }];
}
```

What I don't understand are:

1. The `(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block` part. Assuming that it is a block, does it mean the block is a parameter of the `globalTimelinePostsWithBlock` method?
2. Following the first question, can anyone explain the syntax for me? Why is there a `block` keyword in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't know how blocks work.. then don't bother trying to understand it just by looking at the code (even if you have used lambda/anonymous functions in other languages like javascript or ruby).. b/c the objective-c syntax is a class on it's own..

i'd recommend you take the time to understand block syntax in obj-c on it's own.. then take a look at examples that use them. This [tutorial](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1) is excellent (two parts)..

I did what you did before.. and pulled out half my hair.. after looking at the said tutorial.. my hair grew right back up :)

---

just for fun i'll try to address your specific questions:

**1.The (void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block part. Assuming that it is a block, does it mean the block is a parameter of the globalTimelinePostsWithBlock method?**

yes it is.. so this is a way of calling this method:

```
// first define the block variable
void(^block)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) = (NSArray *posts,NSError *error) {

   // block body
   // posts and error would have been passed to this block by the method calling the block.
   // so if you look at the code sample below.. 
   // posts would be [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutablePosts]
   // and error would just be nil
}

// call the function
[AFNetworking globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:block];
```

**2. Following the first question, can anyone explain the syntax for me? Why is there a block keyword in the end?**

basically the block keyword is the name of the argument.. notice how it's used in the body of the method:

```
if (block) {
            block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutablePosts], nil);
        }
```

again to understand how/why.. i recommend you look at the above article.. learning blocks in obj-c has a bit of learning curve.. but once you master it.. it's an amazing tool. please take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17376708/766570) here to see some sample uses for blocks.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773067/how-to-add-an-extra-argument-to-a-block) is also a sample question/answer that provides a case study of converting delegation into a block based approach, which can also illustrate how blocks work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I guess what I'm asking next is, if the example from the tutorial is: `(int)(^name)(int)`, where the name is positioned after the return type, why is it that on the AFNetworking above, the name (`block`) is written after the parameter?

Comment: they are two different things.. `(int)(^name)(int)` is the name of a variable pointing to a block, whereas `(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block` is an argument *type*, and this argument is referred to as `block`.. it takes a while to sink in.. don't rush it :)

now can i have my +1? ;)

Comment: @hfz if you're still looking into blocks.. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773067/how-to-add-an-extra-argument-to-a-block) out!

Answer (score 1):

The block is passed into the method as something to be called when the API call succeeds. `globalTimelinePostsWithBlock` will call the block passed in with the data (and possibly an `NSError`)

`block` in this case isn't a keyword, it's just the name of the variable.

If you wanted to use `globalTimelinePostsWithBlock`, you would call it like

```
[ClassName globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
  // Check error, then do something with posts
}];
```

(where `ClassName` is the name of the class `globalTimelinePostsWithBlock` is defined on)

Comment: Just to clarify, `block` is never a keyword.  `__block` is a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Block definition are similar to C-functions.

```
(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block
```

- The initial `void` defines the return type of the function.
- The `^` is the block pointer. Similar to `*` for objects.
- `(NSArray *posts, NSError *error)` are the parameters with variable names.
- `block` is the variable in which this block gets stored. (Bad naming here)

Comment: Thanks for answering, especially the `bad naming here` part. It confused me the most and I had a hard time finding why it was used so.