# how to add an extra argument to a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, anonymous-function, mailcore

[Mailcore](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQFjAC&url=http://libmailcore.com/&ei=z-XrUcfKDImLOM7fgbgC&usg=AFQjCNHyISIMiaJPJMU_xwwHDh2FeDayIQ&sig2=pegdrJ4e4irFigyJn-4PRw&bvm=bv.49478099,d.ZWU) has a cool [method](https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore/blob/master/Source/CTBareAttachment.h) that downloads an attachment and accepts a block as a parameter to return download progress:

```
- (CTCoreAttachment *)fetchFullAttachmentWithProgress:(CTProgressBlock)block;
```

where CTProgressBlock is defined as

```
typedef void (^CTProgressBlock)(size_t curr, size_t max);
```

so typically I would use it like so:

```
//AttachmentDownloader.m
int fileNum = x; // explained later
CTCoreAttachment* fullAttachment = 
    [attachment fetchFullAttachmentWithProgress:^(size_t curr, size_t max) {
    NSLog(@"::: this is curr: %zu", curr);
    NSLog(@"::: this is max: %zu\n\n", max);
}];
```

the problem is that this last method is called by my main UI class `FileBucket.m` and this class is in turn fetching many attachments for many different UI elements in sequence. I would like this callback method to report back to `FileBucket.m` which attachment this progress belongs to.. so in other words i want something along the lines of:

```
// FileBucket.m
[AttachmentDownloader runMultiple:attachmentTree 
                     withProgress:^(size_t curr, size_t max, int fileNum) {
    NSLog(@"::: this is curr: %zu", curr);
    NSLog(@"::: this is max: %zu\n\n", max);
    NSLog(@"::: this progress belongs to element %d", fileNum);
}];
```

I know this is hard to explain/illustrate.. one extra thing: `AttachmentDownloader.m` is aware of which attachment this progress is about.. but it just wants to pass it back to `FileBucket.m` *every time* the callback block is called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that class specifically, but in general any block "captures" variables
used inside the block. So this should "just work":

```
int fileNum = x;
CTCoreAttachment* fullAttachment = 
    [attachment fetchFullAttachmentWithProgress:^(size_t curr, size_t max) {
    // ..
    NSLog(@"::: this progress belongs to element %d", fileNum);
}];
```

The block captures the value of the variable at the moment when the block is created.

(It would be slightly different if `fileNum` is declared with the `__block` modifier,
but that is probably not relevant to your problem.)

Comment: I see what you mean, however that's not what I'm looking for.. I just answered my own question.. I hope that would help explain what I had in mind..

Answer (score 0):

the way I figured this out is by breaking it into two steps:

1. implementing what I want through *delegation*
2. converting the delegation into a block based approach.

and since this problem is kind of hard to explain by english, I figured it's best explained by sample code :)

**Delegation Solution:**

```
// AttachmentDownloader.m
+(void)runMultiple:(NSDictionary *)attachmentTree 
      withDelegate:(id<AttachmentDownloaderDelegate>)delegate  {
    ..

    CTCoreAttachment* fullAttachment = 
       [attachment fetchFullAttachmentWithProgress:^(size_t curr, size_t max) {
            NSLog(@"::: this is curr: %zu", curr);
            NSLog(@"::: this is max: %zu\n\n", max);
            NSLog(@"::: this is attachment uid %@", [message uid]);
            [delegate deliverProgressWithInfo:@{@"uid":[message uid],
                                                @"curr":[NSNumber numberWithInt:curr],
                                                @"max":[NSNumber numberWithInt:max]}];
     }];


// FileBucket.m
[AttachmentDownloader runMultiple:attachmentTree withProgress:^(size_t curr, size_t max) {
    NSLog(@"::: this is curr: %zu", curr);
    NSLog(@"::: this is max: %zu\n\n", max);
} withDelegate:self];

// delegate method
-(void)deliverProgressWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSLog(@"filebucket: this is info being updated %@", dict);
}
```

**Block Solution:**

```
// AttachmentDownloader.m
+(void)runMultiple:(NSDictionary *)attachmentTree 
      withProgress:(void(^)(NSDictionary *))block {
    ..

    CTCoreAttachment* fullAttachment = 
        [attachment fetchFullAttachmentWithProgress:^(size_t curr, size_t max) {
        NSLog(@"::: this is curr: %zu", curr);
        NSLog(@"::: this is max: %zu\n\n", max);
        NSLog(@"::: this is attachment uid %@", [message uid]);
        block(@{@"uid":  [message uid],
                @"curr": [NSNumber numberWithInt:curr],
                @"max":  [NSNumber numberWithInt:max]});
    }];


// FileBucket.m
-(void)downloadSelectedAttachments {
    NSDictionary* attachmentTree = [self getAttachmentTree];
    [AttachmentDownloader runMultiple:attachmentTree withProgress:^(NSDictionary * dict) {
        NSLog(@"filebucket: this is info being updated %@", dict);
    }];
}
```