# what does the caret sign mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

There is a piece of code like

```
typedef void (^SignIn) (NSString *email, NSString *password);
```

What does the ^ mean before SignIn? Is this Objective-C specific usage?

Comment: 228/0 Q/A? Is your Google broken?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17691526/766570) is some block syntax explanation using examples

Answer (score 4):

It's the syntax for [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

That typedef declares `SignIn` to mean a block which takes two `NSString*` arguments and returns `void` (i.e. nothing).

Answer (score 1):

It is a block.

For a guide to understanding blocks, see [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2)

Unless, you already know what a block is, and you just didn't know what the caret was for.