# Event on blur and on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I change the following to submit on both `blur` and on `submit`:

```
$('form').on('blur', 'input', function(event) { });
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the form to submit on blur?

Comment: I want the form to submit when the input is changed (on blur) and *also* when the form submit button is clicked.

Comment: But it will always submit by default when the form submit button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to a [named function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions), then re-use the definition, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/an7csxu7/2/):

```
var submitFunction = function(event) {
    // stuff
}

$('input[type=text]').on('blur', submitFunction);
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', submitFunction);
```

Also, you don't need the middle argument to `on()` - you can just use the `$` function to target the elements you want. This means you won't add your click *and* your blur to all `input` elements on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple events to jQuery's `on` method.

```
$('form').on('blur submit', function(event) { })
```

This would mean that whenever the `$('form')` element was either a) blurred or b) submitted, the event handler would be invoked.

Comment: I tried this and it's not submitting when the input is changed (as `blur` does in my question).

Comment: Well, as mentioned, the form will already be submitted when the user clicks the submit button, so this is kind of a weird functionality to ask for. If you want the event handler to submit the form, make sure you're calling `$('form').submit()` within it.

Comment: @Aweary - it would be one way of auto-saving the form contents, if the submit was AJAX, [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) would probably be a better solution for that

Comment: I understand using blur to save the data, but it doesn't make sense to invoke a `submit` event after a `submit` event. There's no reason to submit the form again if we've just submitted it.

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger the submit in blur

```
$('form').on('blur', 'input', function(event) {
     $('form').trigger('submit');
    // or $('form').submit();
 });
```

and for your form submit

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
      // when form submit ...
   });
```