# JavaScript naming of function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, naming-conventions

I'm asking this because I just saw it on a piece of code:

```
var myVar = function func(arg){
   console.log(arg);
}
```

I don't understand why function is "renamed" `func` just before it was defined for `myVar`.

Can somebody explain the interest of doing this, and not just:

```
var myVar = function(arg){
   console.log(arg);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you run this, `func` is `undefined`. So, it is not renaming the `function`

Comment: I agree, maybe I should change the way I explained it, I'm not saying that `func` will exist, but what's the interest of writing it

Comment: I don't see any advantage of using this. As `func` is not defined, you cannot even use it. I'm also keen to know what this is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you have a variable named *myVar*, which has a reference to a function named *func*. Your function isn't renamed.

In the secound example, though, you have the same variable *myVar*, but in this case, it's pointing to an *anonymous* function.

The reason for choosing number one over number two is that you get better output when errors occur, as it will print the function name. In the second example, it will simply say *undefined* if something goes wrong.

Edit: Found a more detailed answer here: [Why use named function expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions)