# Self invoking function written with 'var name = " in the front - bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, knockout.js

In my knockout.js project I wrote some self invoking functions like this:

> ```
> var addMarkers = function () {
>     ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.sectionList(), function (sectionItem) {
>         ko.utils.arrayForEach(sectionItem.placeList(), function (placeItem) {
>             placeItem.marker.addListener('click', function () {
>
>                 map.panTo(placeItem.marker.getPosition());
>             });
>         });
>     });
>
> }();
> ```

The function works without problems, however in JSLint the "var addMarkers" was highlighted as unused variable. That makes me wonder if I should the function like this, or just make anonymous because it is a better practice?:

> `function addMarkers (){    code to be executed  };`

Comment: Your IIFE doesn't returns anything, so `addMarkers` is `undefined`.

Comment: So it is wrong way of writing this function, it just simply doesn't make sense?

Comment: In your code I can't see the necessity to write it in IIFE form, and to your second question `function addMarkers (){    code to be executed  };` It would make the stack trace display the function's name instead of `(anonymous function)`, which makes you easier to trace error. Also, from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15336541/1737627), Names are a Good Thing.

Comment: Clear, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do you know why is it wrapped in a function in the first place?

Comment: Good point it doesn't need to be wrapped at all to make it work... However does this way make it easier to trace error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the result of a self-executing function is often useful. In particular, I like to define my main viewmodel this way, because

1. I don't need a prototype for my viewmodel
2. I'm not likely to need more than one instance of a viewmodel

The reason you would use a self-executing function is that you need a local scope for whatever you're doing, to isolate it from surrounding scope. The reason you would assign a variable from it is that you want it to `return` a value you will use later. In your example, neither of these is true.