# How to get anonymous function to be named in Chrome Timeline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

The Chrome Developer Tools Timeline shows "(anonymous function)" for all of the code that's running slow and so I can't figure out what's going on.  Is there a trick to getting these named?  It also won't allow me to jump to the source of these anonymous functions.  I'm using ES6 w/ arrow functions and babel.

[image: Slow]

Comment: Just [name it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions)? Alternatively, assign it to a variable or property when creating the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use lambda functions in your code. Instead of:

```
async(function(){});
```

write:

```
function withName(){};
async(withName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a named function expression:

```js
function call_callback(cb) {
  cb();
}

function doit() {
  call_callback(function not_anonymous() {
    alert("done");
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doit()">Click me</button>
```

The scope of the name is only the body of the function, but it shows up in the debugger.