# What does it means "var x = function function_name(){}"?

Tags: javascript

I'm the new of JavaScript and I've recently started maintaining someone else's JavaScript code.

The previous code have this block:

```
someObject.someFunction1.someFuction$i_2 = function somefunction$i_3(x,y){...}
```

I want to know what does it means? and Is sign"$" just means simply a valid JavaScript identifier? When I use consolo via Chrome, it show me :

```
typeof someObject = Object
typeof someObject.someFunction1 = function
typeof someObject.someFunction1.someFuction$i_2 = function
typeof somefunction$i_3 = not defined
```

I just know about :

```
var functionOne = function() {
    // Some code
};
```

But, I have no idea about :

```
x = function function_name(){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the way of defining function in javascript
It is commonly called as `named function expression`

```
var x = function function_name(){
  //Rest of the code
}
```

But this function can be called only by calling `x()` but not by `function_name()`. `function_name` only accessible inside the function & is helpful for recursion

Take a look at [**this**](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/different-ways-of-defining-functions-in-javascript-this-is-madness/) & [**this**](http://www.bryanbraun.com/2014/11/27/every-possible-way-to-define-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

1. The `$` sign treated in javaScript in the same way as letters, so it is allowed to have `$` as part of the function name. You even can have

   function $(x) {...}
2. The expression

   x = function function_name(){}

called `named function expression, they are useful when you want to reference the function inside itself. More about why you want to use named function expressions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions)