# Can we call the function by function name after assigning it to a variable.?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Have a function assigned to a variable

var sq = function a(s){return s * s};

Now if i call sq(4) i am getting the result as 16 but if i try to call using the function name a(4) it throws an error "a is not defined"

Can we not call the function by its name once it is assigned to a variable.?

Comment: `var sq = function a(s){return s * s};` is named function expression where only variable is holding the function, not the name of the function...

Comment: You'll want to do `function a(…){…}; var sq = a;`

Comment: I'd say you can't. Why would you do that anyways?

Comment: May be: [__Why use named function expressions?__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions)

Comment: @Bergi, correction var sq=a();

Comment: @Giri var sq = a(); gives you the result of the function, not assigning he function.

Comment: @Giri: No, I meant what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, I know a() only returns the function result. With Begi's comment, var sq=a; 'a' will report undefined.

Comment: @Giri: No, `a` will still refer to the function (which is the whole point)

Comment: @Giri `function a(…){…};` will not make `a` undefined...

Comment: @Giri you may want to let this one go. Go try it for yourself if you think we're all wrong.

Comment: Yep. I was wrong. I've never tried that before.

Comment: @Giri at least you didn't let that stop you from commenting on it... =)

Comment: @Yatrix, its something i learnt.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you're using an assignment. You can just do `var fn = function () { }` or `var fn = ()=> { }` and get the same thing.

If you created the function and then assigned it to a variable, you could do both.

Basically,

`function fn() {...}`

`var myFunc = fn;`

You could then do both:

`myFunc();`
`fn();`