# call function from other file in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm going to scrape around 20 site and for making it a bit easier i want to divide each scrape function for each site in different documents, however when i do that i keep getting

```
function scrape(url, callback) {
       ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

in my index i have this

```
var test = require('../services/test.js');

router.get('/scrape', function(req, res, next) {

  test.scrape("url", function(error){
    if (!error) {
      res.json({succees: "scraped"});
    } else {
      res.json({error: error});
    }

  });

});
```

and in test.js i have something like this

```
module.exports = {

  function scrape(url, callback) {



  }
};
```

Comment: Is there a way I can improve my answer? Just asking as you didn't accept an answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write it like:

```
module.exports = {
    scrape: function(url, callback) {

    }
};
```

in test.js
Then you can call it by `test.scrape();`

It's simply not valid JavaScript to place a function like you did into an object. You have to specify an index in order to be valid. Alternatively it could also be an array:

```
module.exports = [
    function scrape(url, callback) {

    }
];
```

You would call it by `test[0]();` Note that the name *scrape* is optional here. [Why use named function expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions)

Another option:

```
module.exports = function (url, callback) {

};
```

Then you would call it like `test();`

All that is nothing Node.js specific. You can reproduce the same behavior with standard JavaScript by replacing `module.exports` of the above examples with `var test`, accessing the function within the same file.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax you should use is:

```
module.exports = {
  scrape: function(url, callback) {

  }
};
```

As the `module.exports` should point to an object, and the function is field on it.

Take a look [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/), there's a good explanation about it.