# In javascript, I have an array of objects. How do I console log the name of the object, rather than the contents?

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

```
jerry = {
  weight: 178

}

Malcom = {
  weight: 220
}

Bob = {
  Weight: 134

}

people = [jerry, Malcom, Bob]

console.log(people[0]);
```

I'm trying to get a console.log of the object's name, "jerry". thanks for any and all help!

Comment: you can't; objects have no internal name and one object can have 50 different vars refer to it... You can look for it in a certain context and make a match, but that's more of a coincidence than a methodology.

Comment: No need to downvote this -- this is one of those things that can be really unclear to a newbie, since one might not have the baseline knowledge to understand the question.

Comment: Readers may want to note [that assigning function objects to variables *does* preserve the variable name as a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107548/why-does-obj-foo-function-not-assign-the-name-foo-to-the-function), in many cases. It's reasonable to imagine that standard objects could have the same behaviour, but they don't.

Comment: This topic shouldn't be closed. It can be done by some means depending on in which context the objects were defined. [Here](https://repl.it/GV7L) is a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ES6 Version:** Using [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach), and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const jerry = {weight: 178}
const Malcom = {weight: 178}
const Bob = {weight: 178}

const people = {jerry, Malcom, Bob}

const res = Object.entries(people).forEach(([name, {weight}])=>{
  console.log(name, weight);
});
```

---

You can't. Jerry,Malcom, and Bob are just the variable names, you have two obvious solutions:

Add a `name` attribute to your objects.

```
var jerry = {
 name: "jerry",
 weight: 178
}
```

Or change your array to an object, and use the key as the name of your object.

```
var people = {jerry: jerry, malcom: Malcom, bob: Bob}
```

**For example:**

```js
var jerry = {
  weight: 178
}

var Malcom = {
  weight: 178
}

var Bob = {
  weight: 178
}

var people = {jerry: jerry, malcom: Malcom, bob: Bob}

for(var person in people){
  if(people.hasOwnProperty(person)){
    console.log(person, people[person].weight);
  }
}
```

Comment: upvoted for storing people in an objects, and using keys in place of names.

Comment: yeah, I'll use an object instead. thanks a lot.

Comment: ES 2015: `const people = { jerry, malcolm, bob };`

Answer (score -3):

```js
var Some = {
  MyValue : 1234
}
for (var i in Some) console.log(i);
```

```js
var people = {
 jerry : { weight: 178 },
 Malcom : { weight: 220 },
 Bob : { weight: 134 }
}

for (var i in people) console.log( i +' : '+ people[i].weight )
```