# Why isn't it possible to access a javascript function by its original name once it is assigned to a different var?

Tags: javascript, function

```
var f=function foo()
{
console.log("hello");
};

f();
foo();
```

This produces an error as :  "Exception: ReferenceError: foo is not defined"

But "foo" is defined. Why does this happen?I know that this is a function expression and "f()" is used to access this function. But this is not an anonymous function , I do have a name for this function. Why am I not able to access the function using its name?

Comment: See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression) In case of function expression, if you name the function, then the name is only available in the function body and not outside.

Comment: In js all functions are variables. But in your case foo() is assigned to f. 
foo() will get a reference error since it is not defined.

Comment: foo is not defined. f is defined.

Comment: This syntax is called a named function expression. That name is not it's original name, it's a local variable (local to the function) that refers to the function itself so that you can write recursive anonymous functions. The function **does not have a name** - it's anonymous. Some older browsers leaked the variable into global scope so behaving like what you expected but this is considered a bug. These days all browsers I know of have fixed the bug thus the name is no longer accessible outside the function

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Big help.

Answer (score 6):

MDN  - function expression

syntax

```
var myFunction = function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) {
   statements
};
```

> The function name. Can be omitted, in which case the function is anonymous. The name is only local to the function body.

Answer (score 2):

You are conflating *function expressions* with *function declarations*.

This declares a variable `foo` and assigns an anonymous function to it:

```
var foo = function() {};
```

This declares a function `bar` in the current scope:

```
function bar() {};
```

This declares a variable `baz` and assigns it a function whose name is `qux`:

```
var baz = function qux() {};
```

Note that in this case, the function is not being declared in this scope. Only the variable is being declared. It just so happens that the name property of this function will be set to `qux`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions?rq=1).

Edit: code blocks
Edit: added relevant link