# Can isNaN be used as identifier in a named function expression?

Tags: javascript, polyfills, function-expression

**The context**:

I am reading the book [*You Don't Know JS: Up & Going*, *Chapter 2: Into JavaScript*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). In the *Polyfilling* section, the author gives the following example:

```
if (!Number.isNaN) {
    Number.isNaN = function isNaN(x) {
        return x !== x;
    };
}
```

So, what is being done here is creating a polyfill so that the ES6 method [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) can run in older browsers (ie, pre-ES6 versions). As I expected, he makes use of the older [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) method. The former method is actually meant to deprecate the latter by design.

**The question**:

Why is isNaN being used as the *identifier* of the named [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)? I would have expected it to be used in the *body* somehow. Why? Because all of the identifiers usually seen in examples around the web, when comparing function expressions vs function declarations take the following form:

Function declaration:

```
function foo() {
    // ..
}
```

Function expression:

```
var foo = function bar() {
    // ..
};
```

So in this example *bar* is being defined within the brackets after the 'bar()' string. So why use 'isNaN' above when *isNaN* is an already defined function within JavaScript? Are we actually overwriting it for the purpose of the polyfill? What am I missing/misunderstanding here?

Comment: naming the function that way doesn't really do anything to the old `isNaN`, it's mostly done for stack traces or to be able to reference the function from within itself. In this example the function could just as well be anonymous.

Comment: `Function declaration` - will be created BEFORE code execution, `Function expression` - will be created, when line of code with initialization will be riched by interpreter.

in your case this prevents overwriting a function `isNaN` before check

Comment: @AndrewEvt I understand both definitions and how the Engine treats one and the other. However I don't understand your second sentence: "in your case this prevents overwriting a function isNaN before check". Can you explain what you mean? How is overwriting prevented, and as opposed to which case?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a named function in an expression, that value is not hoisted but is saved in expression scope. So original value is not changed.

**Sample**

```js
function bar(){
  console.log("In Bar")
}

var foo = function bar(){
  console.log("In Foo")
}

bar();
foo();
```

**Why should you use it?**

In case of exception, that will help you in debug. An anonymous function will not show any name in stack trace and if you have say 4-5 anonymous functions in 1 function, it becomes difficult as to which one failed. Having a named functions makes it little simple.

```js
var bar = function Test() {
  (function() {
    (function() {
      (function() {
        throw new Error("I have no Name2")
      })()
    })()
  })()
}

var foo = function Test() {
  (function inFoo1() {
    (function inFoo2() {
      (function inFoo3() {
        throw new Error("I have no Name2")
      })()
    })()
  })();
}


function init() {
  try {
    foo();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.stack)
  }
  try {
    bar();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.stack)
  }
}

function start() {
  init();
}

start();
```

You can also refer to [Why using named function expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336347/why-use-named-function-expressions) for more information.