# Difference between inside or outside definition of a named event handler for addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent

In the example below, the ball is -as expected- being dropped when the mouseup event occurs:

```js
ball.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};

ball.onmousedown = function(e) {
  let ballRect = ball.getBoundingClientRect();
  let shiftX = e.pageX - ballRect.left;
  let shiftY = e.pageY - ballRect.top;

  ball.style.position = "absolute";
  ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
  document.body.append(ball);

  function moveball(x, y) {
    ball.style.left = x + "px";
    ball.style.top = y + "px";
  }

  moveball(e.pageX - shiftX, e.pageY - shiftY);

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove);
    ball.onmouseup = null;
  });

  function onmousemove(e) {
    moveball(e.pageX - shiftX, e.pageY - shiftY);
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove);
}
```

```css
#court {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#ball {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="court">
  <div id="ball">
  <div>
</div>
```

but when the `onmousemove` function definition is put inside the `addEventListener` function, the ball is not dropped when the mouseup event occurs (against the expectation) :

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function onmousemove(e) {
  moveball(e.pageX - shiftX, e.pageY - shiftY);
});
```

How does defining the named event handler inside or outside the `addEventListener` make a difference?

Comment: `document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove);` does NOT remove `document.addEventListener('mousemove', function onmousemove(e) {
  moveball(e.pageX - shiftX, e.pageY - shiftY);
});` because there is no function named `onmousemove` - since the `onmousemove` is just a name for the function expression

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah... so it's scoped differently! Thank you.

Comment: no, not scoped differently exactly ... a named function expression isn't the same as a declared function

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok, now I think I get it, if I'm not wrong once again, it's a _named function expression_: "One key thing about a named function expression is that it creates an in-scope identifier with that name for the function within the functon body" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15336541/9868445). Thanks again.

Comment: sounds right, so I guess "scope" does have something to do with it :p

Answer (score 1):

From MDN:

> The function expression's name can be used only within the function's
> body. Attempting to use it outside the function's body results in an
> error or undefined.

```js
var y = function x() { return "Hello"; };
alert(x()); // throws an error
```

In contrast:

> A function declaration creates a variable with the same name as the
> function name. Thus, unlike those defined by named function
> expressions, functions defined by function declarations "can be
> accessed by their name" in the scope they were defined in:

```js
function x() { return "Hello"; };
alert(x()); // Hello
```