# Can we assign a function declaration to a variable in javascript like we do for function expression?

Tags: javascript, function

What I learned is there are three ways function can be defined : a) Function Declaration b) Function Expression c) Arrow Function

Function Expression and arrow function can be simply defined and assigned to a variable but we cant do this for Function Declaration.. Am i right?

but I tried a code as follow:

```
const square_a_num = function square_the_num(num){
    return num**2
}
const square_45 = square_a_num(45)
console.log(square_45);
```

I think the way I defined  the function above is  Function declaration but still I was able to assign it to a variable., and it is still working.

I hoped if I declared it like a function expression like below then only I can assign it to a variable :

```
const square_a_num = function(num){
    return num**2
}
const square_45 = square_a_num(45)
console.log(square_45);
```

Where I am making mistake?
Thanks

I thought it should have given me an error message but rather it gave  me the output as 2025 .

Comment: A function expression with a name is still a function expression, not a function declaration. Discussion on anon vs. named FEs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15336347/3001761.

Comment: A function declaration statement starts with the keyword `function`.

Comment: const square_a_num = function(num){
    return num**2
}
const square_45 = square_a_num(45)
console.log(square_45);                                                                                                              But in this also there is function keyword used , so is it Function declaration or function declaration.

Comment: _"is it Function declaration or function declaration"_ - ...neither? It's a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) - they still use the `function` keyword (that's just not the _start_ of the statement), and can still have names.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    const square_a_num = function square_the_num(num){
>        return num**2
>    }
>    const square_45 = square_a_num(45)
>    console.log(square_45);
> ```
>
> I think the way I defined the function above is Function declaration but still I was able to assign it to a variable., and it is still working.

This is still interpreted as a function expression, except that it has a name.

This allows function expressions to be recursive.

[Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_expressions)

If you try to execute `square_the_num()` outside of it's own scope, you will get:

`ReferenceError: square_the_num is not defined`