# Connection between functions - jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

r.redrawSlider(); <---- PLACE 1

})


(function(e) {

(..)

e.fn.bxSlider = function(s) {

(..)

r.redrawSlider = function() {
  o.children.add(r.find(".bx-clone")).width(p()), o.viewport.css("height", h()), o.settings.ticker || m(), o.active.last && (o.active.index = f() - 1), o.active.index >= f() && (o.active.last = !0), o.settings.pager && !o.settings.pagerCustom && (b(), M(o.active.index));
}

(..)

}

(..)

})(jQuery)
```

Is it possible to execute r.redrawSlider function in `PLACE 1`?

................................................................

Comment: Hi, see the link, this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function/12093389#12093389 After creating your jquery function you can use PLACE 1

Comment: @Macko Tarana The object "r" should be global