# Not able to define function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing something like

```
(function($){

  function showAlert(){
    alert('test');
  }

})(jQuery);
```

and when I tried to run showAlert(), it's saying showAlert() is not defined.

Can anyone suggest why ?

Comment: Where do you call `showAlert`?

Comment: The real question is: where are you trying to access the function from? If the rest of your jQuery *was inside the same function closure* it would work :)

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're calling that function outside IEFE function.

Calling it outside won't work as it is not in global scope. The IEFE is creating a closure of which , `showAlert` becomes a part and not of global scope which is `window`

Do this:

```
(function($){
  window.showAlert = function(){
    alert('test');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

It doesn't make sense to put a function declaration inside IEFE unless otherwise it is a jquery plugin. So, just remove it:

```
function showAlert(){
   alert('test');
}
```

Comment: @RGraham, in this case, it is securing the `$` variable

Answer (score 1):

The [scope of a variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope) in javascript is either

- the global scope
- the function in which it is defined

`showAlert` is a variable. It's only available in the scope of the external function you wrote.

If you want to define a function for the external scope, define it in the external scope.

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
function showAlert(x) {
   alert(x);
}

showAlert($('#anyElementId').val());
```

Assign the variable X for function and your alert. Then pass your element val into your function call.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94ZtT/

Comment: If I define it like this, it works, but I can't access any element using say $('#anyElementId').val() etc.

Comment: Pass var into function like so function showAlert(x) {
   alert(x);
}

showAlert($('#anyElementId').val());

Answer (score 0):

You're Creating A function inside a `self executing anonymus function` ie. `$(document).ready()` or `$(function()...`.

So your function is in local scope of that function. Simply Means You cant access that in outside of that function.

So to make it accessible just make it global.

In JavaScript `window` is global object. So to make your function global, use that object as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function showAlert()() {
        alert('test');
    }

    window.showAlert=showAlert();  //NOTE THIS, IT IS IMPORTANT.

});
```

Now you can access it elsewhere in your JS.

Here is working

## [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/EGsdf/3/)

Hope it'll help you! cheers :)..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend jQuery with your function just add function to jQuery object. 
Like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.extend({
        showAlert: function () {
           alert('test');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Separate this code into file with name jquery.showAlert.js, include it after jquery library 
and after this you can use function in this way:

```
$.showAlert()
```

Best regards.