# Create jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I would like to know how to create jquery function that I could then call with parameters name and value declared in it.

Instead of giving in correct order variables to function like this:

```
myFunction("My function name",true,false);
```

I would like to give to function something like that:

```
function({
  displayName: "My function name",
  editable: true,
  displayForm: false;
})
```

where order of parameters dosnt matter, cause I am giving it by theier name.

I've saw that configuration in every jquery lib (jqPlot,JqGrid,noty etc.)
Here is example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [cosPoints], {  
      series:[{showMarker:false}],
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          label:'Angle (radians)'
        },
        yaxis:{
          label:'Cosine'
        }
      }
  });
});
```

--Edited--

I have my own js function to print trees from json, but I have so much parameters, that it is so hard to read and edit.

Comment: Do you want to create a function or a jquery extension?

Comment: Just pass the object as a parameter and use it within the function.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own jQuery plugin?

Comment: Did you see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't do what you are asking, just have your function expect an object literal:

```
function MyFunction(o){
    // Do whatever you need to do with your object properties,
    // like set some corresponding scoped variables.
    // 0 would be their default values, change as appropriate.
    var displayName = o.displayName || 0,
        editable = o.editable || 0,
        displayForm = o.displayForm || 0;
}
```

Then call it how you wanted:

```
myFunction({
    displayName: "My function name",
    editable: true,
    displayForm: false;
});
```

For the record, there is no jQuery functionality here. This is all vanilla JavaScript.

---

Note, if you *are* using jQuery, you could check that the parameter is in fact an object literal before going on to carry out functionality, with [`$.isPlainObject(o)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isplainobject/).

Comment: Beat me to it. The most solid solution. Except for the default values which should probably be in sync with the expected datatypes.

Comment: @Jonast92 Sure, but in this case I'm not going to go ahead and assume data-types. I will add a note though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare your function taking an object as the argument :

```
function myFunction(obj) {
    if(obj.displayName) {
    // do something with obj.displayName
    }

    // ....
}
```

And you can call it as you indicated :

```
myFunction({
    displayName: "My function name",
    editable: true,
    displayForm: false;
});
```

or even with this :

```
myFunction({
    editable: true,
    displayForm: false;
});
```

In order to test if a property exists in your object passed as the argument, just put the test as I have done : `obj.myProperty`.

Another point is that you can put default values with [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) :

```
function myFunction(obj) {
    var myDefaults = {
        displayName: "My default name",
        editable: false
    };

    // Fill `obj` with the missing values that have to be supplied
    // and that we take in `myDefaults`
    $.extend(obj, myDefaults);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Extension

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    zigzag: function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var zigzagText = '';
        var toggle = true; //lower/uppper toggle
            $.each(text, function(i, nome) {
                zigzagText += (toggle) ? nome.toUpperCase() : nome.toLowerCase();
                toggle = (toggle) ? false : true;
            });
    return zigzagText;
    }
});

console.log($('#tagline').zigzag());
//output: #1 jQuErY BlOg fOr yOuR DaIlY NeWs, PlUgInS, tUtS/TiPs &amp; cOdE SnIpPeTs.

//chained example
console.log($('#tagline').zigzag().toLowerCase());
//output: #1 jquery blog for your daily news, plugins, tuts/tips &amp; code snippets.
```

For more references you can check : http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` is just shorthand for an object.

Take this example

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
```

If you pass that as an unnamed object to a function, you can pick our the values from that. For example:

```
function myFunc( myArg ){
    alert( myArg.firstName );
}
```

and call it with

```
myFunc({firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is working properly if you just pass your object as parameter to the function.

```
test({a:"TestA", b:"TestB"});

function test(object)
{
    alert(object.a);
    alert(object.b);
}
```