# Javascript&Jquery why can't my animate() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some code, which is shown beneath. I couldn't figure out why hideDialog() can work, but showDialog() doesn't work.Can anybody tell me what wrong is with my code, or give me some information to search? Thanks:)

Here is the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).showDialog is not a function

```
function showDialog(){
      this.animate({
          top:50
      },{ 
          duration:400,
          effect:'slide',
          easing:'easeOutBack'
      }); 
  }

  function hideDialog(){
      this.animate({
          top:-200
      },{ 
          duration:400,
          effect:'slide',
          easing:'easeInBack'
      });
  }

  function initSetting(){
      $('.form-control').change(function(){
          $('#myAlertDialog').showDialog();
          $('#myAlertDialog').find('btnOk').on('click',function(){
              $('#myAlertDialog').hideDialog();
          });   
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to re frame your code like this,

```
function showDialog($this){
      $this.animate({
          top:50
      },{ 
          duration:400,
          effect:'slide',
          easing:'easeOutBack'
      }); 
 }

  function hideDialog($this){
      $this.animate({
          top:-200
      },{ 
          duration:400,
          effect:'slide',
          easing:'easeInBack'
      });
  }

  function initSetting(){
      $('.form-control').change(function(){
          showDialog($('#myAlertDialog'));
          $('#myAlertDialog').find('btnOk').on('click',function(){
              hideDialog($('#myAlertDialog'));
          });   
      });
  }
```

Or [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function-create-a-new-jquery-method-or-plugin) to know how to create user defined functions on top of jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I like the answer in the link. However, I still have a question, I believe that the "this" in showDialog() is $('#myAlertDialog'), but why can't the function work? Or is there anything wrong with the call?

Comment: @Chiu `this` inside that function will be window object not `$('#myAlertDialog')`.

Comment: @Chiu jquery object won't have any user defined functions with it unless you defined it.

Comment: I've tried writing `console.log(this)` in front of this.animate(), and the console printout error message instead of my custom message. It seems that  the function isn't called correctly in the `initSetting()`. Is anything wrong with my thought?

Comment: OK I get the point. thanks:) but why can the hideDialog in initSetting wrong correctly, Ijust can't figure out this LOL

Answer (score 0):

use `$.fn.showDialog()` instead of just `function showDialog()`.
use `$.fn.hideDialog()` instead of just `function hideDialog()`.
 **You're trying to extend the jQuery prototype.**

Please see [What is $.fn.function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean) and [Plugins
How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check out the link, after I understand the idea of prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Try to frame your code like this. Further, read about the difference between this and $(this) in jQuery.

```
function showDialog(item){
      $(item).animate({
          top:50,
          duration:400,
          effect:'slide',
          easing:'easeOutBack'
      }); 
 }   // end of showDialog

  function hideDialog(item){
      $(item).animate({
          top:-200,
          duration:400,
          effect:'slide',
          easing:'easeInBack'
      });
  }   // end of hideDialog

  function initSetting(){
      $('.form-control').change(function(){
          showDialog($('#myAlertDialog'));
          $('#myAlertDialog').find('btnOk').on('click',function(){
              hideDialog($('#myAlertDialog'));
          });   
      });
  }

  // btnOK should have a # or . for the identifier.
  // if the click event does not work, then try with the delegate() function. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
```