# How to run different pieces of code whether an element is clicked once or twice (not talking about double click)?

Tags: jquery

My menu aims at navigating within the same long page. Only one menu item (corresponding to the section of the page being viewed currently) is visible by default. A click on that visible menu item reveals the whole menu.

Here's the trick: once the menu is revealed, another click (not talking abut double click here) on a menu item should trigger something else, namely scrolling to the area associated with the item (off topic here). Is it achievable with `jQuery` alone?

Somehow I need to make the `alert()` part execute only on the second click, not the first.

Here's my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/v6rLs1rg/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.current').click(function() {
    $('.menu_item').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.menu_item').click(function() {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_item {
  display: none;
}

.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu_item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item current">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    Item 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `.one("click", function() )`. This will make that code execute only once.

Comment: you can add a counter to your script to count the second click - e.g. `var count = 0;` and then inside your `click` function do: `count++`

Comment: Why this does not work as expected beats me: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m921p4ou/

Comment: @mplungjan,   `$('.menu_item').not(".current").on` is not dynamic enough: the `current` class will be moved around, but this is only executed once, and thus static.

Comment: @trincot any suggestions ? I do not get why it would not work - no delegation expected

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs could you create an answer so I can accept it please? Your solution is the simplest and works perfectly!

Comment: @drake035 sure will do now :)

Comment: @mplungjan, well, you just hinted at it: you could use delegation, so that you dynamically know which is the current element, and which not (a changing fact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way you can count a click (or anything for that matter) is by using a counter variable:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var counter = 0,        //its traditional to set this to 0 - but can be whatever you want
            example = [1, 2, 3] //overall count is 3

        $.each('.class', function()
        {
            counter++;
        });

        alert(counter); //should alert 2 (as counter started on 0)
    });
</script>
```

and that's a basic example of a counter - in your case for counting when it's the second click (or any more after that) you can do an if statement (or a switch statement if it's more than one) like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var counter = 0;

        $('#someBtn').on('click', function()
        {
            counter++;

            switch (counter)
            {
                case 1:
                    actionOne();            
                    break;
                case 2:
                    actionTwo();
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this should be what you're looking for.

NOTE: `counter--` can be used to count down

Answer (score 0):

Place the second `click` function inside the `.current` `click` function.
The second click function will now get triggered because it only runs after you clicked `.current`.

After doing this you will notice that `alert()` will run twice. You can fix this by replacing `$('.menu_item').click()` to `$('.menu_item').on('click')`

**Fiddle**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.current').click(function() {
    $('.menu_item').fadeIn();
    

  $('.menu_item').on("click", function() {
    alert('test');
  });
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_item {
  display: none;
}

.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu_item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item current">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    Item 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using custom function chaining, you can assign the click events right after you do your jquery's fade in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992651/jquery-chaining-custom-functions

  $.fn.activateClicks = function() {
    isFadedIn = true;
    $('.menu_item').click(function() {
      alert('test');
    });
    return this; //The magic statement
  }
  var isFadedIn = false;
  $('.current').click(function() {
    if(!isFadedIn){
      $('.menu_item').fadeIn().activateClicks();
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one click handler and let it determine in which state it is being called.

I would suggest not to detach/re-attach event handlers, as in practice you don't really need to worry about clicks being made on hidden elements.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.menu_item').click(function() {
    $siblings = $(this).siblings(".menu_item");
    if ($siblings.filter(":visible").length) { // more items visible
      $siblings.fadeOut().removeClass("current");
    } else { // it's the only visible one
      $siblings.fadeIn();
    }
    // Always select the clicked element
    $(this).addClass("current");
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_item {
  display: none;
}

.current {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu_item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item current">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    Item 3
  </div>
</div>
```