# Function is not found in Jquery, but is found in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclick

I have an html document in which a function is called like this
`<div id="mon" class="topbar" onclick="verd()">`
This calls a jquery function inside the body tag that goes like this

```
<script src="jquery.js">
  function verd(){
    $("#stillmain").empty();
  }  </script>
```

This returns the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: verd is not defined
at HTMLDivElement.onclick
```

When I change the script to pure Javascript without Jquery however like this

```
  <script>
  function verd(){
    $("#stillmain").empty();
  }  </script>
```

it does recognize the function verd(), can anyone explain what is going on, and how I could still use Jquery?
I am using the newest version of Jquery(just changed the name, nothing else).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you give a `script` tag a `src` attribute it's going to load that source file in place of the `script` contents. So any `script` tags with a `src` should be kept empty.

You need to load jQuery by calling a `script` tag with its source on it, and then in a separate tag you can make your own `script` tag and write your custom JavaScript there.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function verd(){
    $("#stillmain").empty();
  }
</script>
```

Make sure that your custom scripts are loaded after jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this as a jQuery function you need to use the proper syntax. Try the link below.

[How to Create a jQuery Function](http://ahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function-a-new-jquery-method-or-plugin)

Also, you need to load jQuery in a separate  tag or else none of your code will be ran other than the source of that script!