# Uncaught ReferenceError - how to access function bundled by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask for a project and I'm trying to add a javascript function to a js file that's bundled by webpack and access it from the html. I think I'm missing something basic.

Source files for background:

- https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/webpack.config.js
- https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/assets/js/plugins.js

I'm adding the following code to plugins.js:

```
function foo () {
    console.log('bar')
}
```

And trying to call it from an html document to test as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    foo();
</script>
```

I can see that my function got bundled, but I can't access it.
[image: output code]

And here's the error I get:
[image: Error in browser]

I already had to add expose-loader to my webpack.config.js to get jquery to work as per [this issue](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/issues/185):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experiene, when I am using Webpack, I am bundling code into modules, which encapsulates them to that module's scope.  Code that I want to be available outside of the module I explicitly `export`, and then `import` or `require` it into the new scope where I want to access it.

It sounds like you are instead wishing for some of your code to be accessible in the *global* scope, to access it directly from your markup.  To do this in the browser, your best bet is to attach it directly to the `Window` object.  Probably first checking to make sure that you aren't overwriting something already at that namespace:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('bar!');
}

if (!Window.foo) {
    Window.foo = foo;
} else {
    console.warn('Foo is already assigned!');
}
```

That said, I would recommend you avoid developing in this manner-- polluting the global namespace is usually not a great pattern, and leads to a lot of potential conflict.  If you *must* work in this manner, at least assign an object to a namespace attached to `Window` where you can put your applications functionality without risking conflicting with other `Window` properties:

```
Window.myApp = {
    foo: function () {
        console.log('bar!');
    }
}

Window.myApp.printGreeting = function () {
    console.log('Hello!');
}

// ...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alexander. I'm happy defining a module. What I'm getting stuck on is the syntax. What does a simple module that just has one function that logs a line look like? How do I then import it? In particular, webpack is generating a JS file with a hash so I'm not sure what to put in after from, for example 'import Module from '

Comment: @sshevlyagin - it depends on if you're using ES6 syntax or Node module syntax.  If you're using ES6, you should check out the [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) pages on MDN.  Generally, I would say if you are exporting only a single function from a module you can use `export default myFunction`.  Then it can be `import`ed w/ whatever name you want: `import theFunction from './../someFolder/myFunction'`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I did some more experimentation, and it seems the way the webpack is setup the js file I'm adding things to is expecting jquery. I'm going to post how I fixed this in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to get ES6 syntax to work in the file, kept running into this error:
[image: error]

Here's a workaround based on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function-a-new-jquery-method-or-plugin)
[image]