# how to do $(element).function({})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add functions/methods to certain elements but instead of select all or just those with classes I want to select them in the template within a script tag.

I've seen many plugins that do these but I can't think of a way to create such functions/methods.

What I mean is like this `$('#select').selectize({})`

I would only need to know how to pass the element to the function/method. I've tried searching for it but I have no clue what to search for. The best I've came up with was like this

template: `upload($(element), {})`
js: `function upload(object, settings) {}`

Unfortunately since I have no idea what this is called I can't really create a proper title for this question

Comment: You can use `event` and you can obtain details about element which triggers that event,

Comment: If you try to explain what you are trying to achieve instead, we might be able to help you better

Comment: You mean something like this: [How to create a jQuery function (a new jQuery method or plugin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12093192/4642212)?

Comment: Xufox exactly what I meant. Thank you so much :)