# Apply a function to an id element

Tags: jquery, function

i am trying to apply a function to an html id element.
I am at the first step
And it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).myfunction is not a function
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8cxb3nkt/

Here is the html code:

```
<img src=myimage.jpg id=image___1>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
    function myfunction(){
        console.log('oooooooook');
            }
            
            jQuery('#image___1').myfunction();
```

Thanks all very much

Comment: Try take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function-a-new-jquery-method-or-plugin

Comment: Start here: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Hi,
i would like to add an action to an image. For this example it could be change the image source if i hover the image

(It must be the real basic of javascript, but i dont where to begin with)

Thanks